# Matrix view generated from two selected columns of a table

Tags: sql, database, view, pivot

Suppose i have a table containing `Project_type`, `Project_No`, `OS_Platform` columns. Here I have limited `Project_type`s and limited `OS_Platform`s. I want a database view which produces a matrix between `Project_type` and `OS_Platform`.

```
 MY_TABLE : 
 Project_Type     Project_No       OS_Platform 
 Drivers          345              Linux
 WebService       453              Windows                    
 Drivers          034              Windows            
 Drivers          953              Solaris
 DesktopApp       840              Windows 
 WebService       882              Solaris
```

Now I have `Project_type` and `OS_Platform` as selected columns. I want a matrix view of these two columns with distinct rows and column names.

```
Project_Type     Linux    Windows     Solaris
WebService       null      true         true
Drivers          true      true         true
DesktopApp       null      true         null
```

Can anyone tell me if it is possible. How is that possible ?

Comment: By "limited," do you mean you know all the possible values of each?  If so, this becomes easy.

Comment: yes all the possible values are known .. but i am not interested in values which are not participating

Answer (score 3):

You could also try using the dedicated PIVOT feature if it is supported by the SQL product you are using. For instance, the following [would work in SQL Server 2005+](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a77e/6):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    Project_Type,
    'true' AS flag,
    OS_Platform
  FROM MY_TABLE
) s
PIVOT (
  MAX(flag)
  FOR OS_Platform IN (
    Linux, Windows, Solaris
  )
) p
;
```

Oracle Database is another product that supports PIVOT, although I'm not sure in which version it was first introduced. You would be able to run the above query [in Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08181/3) after enclosing every column in the PIVOT's IN list in single quotes, like this:

```
... IN (
  'Linux', 'Windows', 'Solaris'
)
...
```

Comment: It is working fine and was able to learn about the new concept PIVOT. Thnx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a `PIVOT` query where you transpose your rows of data into columns.  The easiest way to perform this since you want a `true/null` value is using an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement:

```
select project_type,
  max(case when os_platform ='Linux' then 'true' else null end) Linux,
  max(case when os_platform ='Windows' then 'true' else null end) Windows,
  max(case when os_platform ='Solaris' then 'true' else null end) Solaris
from yourtable
group by project_type
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b2f5/1)

The result is:

```
| PROJECT_TYPE |  LINUX | WINDOWS | SOLARIS |
---------------------------------------------
|   DesktopApp | (null) |    true |  (null) |
|      Drivers |   true |    true |    true |
|   WebService | (null) |    true |    true |
```

Comment: @user1860322 Happy to help, if any of the answers are helpful to you, then be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left of it.  It helps future visitors and you get rep for accepting.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pivot/unpivot your values to transpose them into your format of choice.

Here's a google search for pivot on stack overflow.  Any of these will do you fine.  https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+pivot+unpivot+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=sql+pivot+unpivot+site%3Astackoverflow.com&aqs=chrome.0.57.9985&sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Now, there are 2 types of answers you'll see there.  The first is a regular pivot/unpivot operation.  These work very well (easily, not fast) with *known* data sets.  That is, if you know all project types and platforms, this will work fine.

The second type is a dynamic pivot, or a pivot created by using dynamic SQL.  This is messier, but allows you any combination of fields.

Good luck!